# How to match an argument with dots in Rust macros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am writing a program and it contains a lot of `match`blocks as I keep calling methods and functions that return `Result` struct type results.

So I was thinking maybe a macro will reduce the amount of code.

And the final macro is like this:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! ok_or_return {
    //when calls on methods
    ($self: ident, $method: ident($($args: tt)*), $Error: ident::$err: ident) => {{
        match $self.$method($($args)*) {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => {
                dbg!(e);
                return Err($Error::$err);
            }
        }
    }};
}
```

As yo can see, I use `$($args: tt)*` to match multiple arguments, and it goes pretty well. Even when I use `struct.method()` as a form of argument, it compiled.
Like:

```rust
ok_or_return!(self, meth(node.get_num()), Error::GetNumError);
```

However, if I use the same form to match a normal macro argument, it failed. I changed the specifier to `tt`, and it didn't work out. Like:

```rust
ok_or_return!(self.people, meth(node.get_num()), Error::GetNumError);
```

So my problem is why `node.get_num()` can be matched and `self.people` can't?

Comment: I don't think you need this macro. Using `self.meth(...).map_err(|Error_GetNumError)?` should do the same thing, and isn't any longer than your macro call.

Comment: If you implement `From<SomeError>` for your `Error` type for all relevant errors, you can even simply use `self.meth(...)?`, and the conversion will be performed automatically. Implementing the `From` traits can be simplified using the `thiserror` crate.

Comment: That said, if you really want to use a macro, I think the you should accept the full match expression as the first argument, using the `expr` designator.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I never think of that in this way. I will try it, thanks a lot.